# How to update one field in Array of Json Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am doing reactjs so I need to update a field in away that will trigger state change.

I have this payload(only show 1 but it is an array of many)

```
    [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Fridge2",
                    selected: true,
                    sharingId: 'ae9b9566-3b5c-4772-a0a1-07ed8b354b8f',
                    sharingWith: ["jim@hotmail.com", "jim2@hotmail.com"],
                    storageItems: [
                        {
                            id: 'ae9b9564-3b5c-2711-a421-07ed8b354b8f',
                            name: 'Chicken Breats',
                            qty: 10,
                            expiresOn: '3',
                            category: 'Meat',
                            categoryId: 'BDEC0494-B16E-411B-8E32-A64A00E943F8',
                            unitType: 'Pieces',
                            unitTypeId: '63CDB076-C20D-4DC5-A181-A64A00E94409'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'ae9b9566-3b5c-2711-a4a1-07ed8b354b8f',
                            name: 'Chicken Breats2',
                            qty: 10,
                            expiresOn: '0',
                            category: 'Meat',
                            categoryId: 'BDEC0494-B16E-411B-8E32-A64A00E943F8',
                            unitType: 'Pieces',
                            unitTypeId: '63CDB076-C20D-4DC5-A181-A64A00E94409'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'ae9b9566-3b5c-2712-a0a1-07ed8b354b8f',
                            name: 'Chicken Breats3',
                            qty: 10,
                            expiresOn: '4',
                            category: 'Meat',
                            categoryId: 'BDEC0494-B16E-411B-8E32-A64A00E943F8',
                            unitType: 'Pieces',
                            unitTypeId: '63CDB076-C20D-4DC5-A181-A64A00E94409'
                        }
                    ]
                }
]
```

I want to find storageItem that matches the an ID 'ae9b9564-3b5c-2711-a421-07ed8b354b8f' (first one in the array)

I then want to take it out update the a field(say qty) stick it back in and have a state change happen.

This was my very bad 1st attemp at it. It does not work

```
case actions.STORAGE_ITEM_USED: {
            var foundItem = state.selectedStorage.storageItems.filter(i => i.id == action.payload);
            var newQty = foundItem[0].qty - 1;
            foundItem[0].qty = newQty;
            var nonChangedStorageItem = state.selectedStorage.storageItems.filter(i => i.id != action.payload);

            var allItems = nonChangedStorageItem.concat(foundItem);
            state.selectedStorage.storageItems = allItems;

            return {
                selectedStorage: state.selectedStorage,
            }

        }
```

Edit

I have this now but I see a new possible answer that I will checkout

```
var newSelectedStorage =  Object.assign({} , state.selectedStorage);

   var foundItem = newSelectedStorage.storageItems.filter(x => x.id == action.payload);
   foundItem[0].qty = foundItem[0].qty - 1;

   var nonChangedItems = newSelectedStorage.storageItems.filter(x => x.id != action.payload);

   newSelectedStorage.storageItems = nonChangedItems.concat(foundItem);
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: "./app/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./app",
    inline: true,
    port: 3333
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
   externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
}
```

Comment: I believe the issue is that you are mutating the original object, then returning it.  Redux expects a *new* object to completely overwrite the state.  You might be able to get away with `Object.assign`-ing your existing state, mutating that, and returning it.

Comment: New Object for SelectedStorage I am guessing?

Comment: Redux state handlers return an entirely new state object, so the reference has to change.  There are some shortcuts to make this really easy, using ES6's spread operators - Dan goes through it all in [his Redux tutorials](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, you're trying to decrease the `qty` property on any matching objects in `state.selectedStorage.storageItems`.

Since Redux needs a whole new object, we can use ES6's object spread operators to return a new object with most of the values already filled in.

```
case actions.STORAGE_ITEM_USED:
    return {
        ...state,
        selectedStorage: state.selectedStorage.storageItems.map(i => {
            if (i.id != action.payload) return i;
            return {
                ...i,
                qty: i.qty - 1
            }
        })
    }
```

I can't test if this works, but the idea is that we are returning a new object, copying existing state objects, then overwriting `selectedStorage` with a new array where only items whose `id`s matching `action.payload`'s `qty` properties are decreased.

Comment: I am in process checking this out. On a side note what do I need to get "...state" to work? In Visual Studio code I get red underline under the 3 dots saying "properly assignment expected". Get same problem with ...i

Comment: `state` is your state object, which is the first argument in your reducer (`action` is the second argument).  The three dots `...` is part of ES6's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and ["rest"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) syntax.  If you're working with React/Redux, you're likely using Babel, so by simply including the `babel-preset-es2015` preset, it should transpile fine.

Comment: I do have babel-prset-es2015. I think this is an issue with Visual studio code. I used the 3 dots before for ...props with no problems but I get problems here Unexpected token (134:18) when I build it via webpack.

Comment: Hmm, [a basic recreation](https://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/7gnLakr4/) works for me here on JSFiddle - is Babel [set up as a loader](https://github.com/ScottKaye/mail-frontend/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L25) for your `.js` files?

Comment: I will post my webpack.config but I think the issue is that Visual Studio Code ide is causing the problem.

Comment: @chobo2 Ah, you need at least [stage-2](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) in your Babel presets to work with [object spreads](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)!

Comment: That worked I still get the red dots in Visual studio code but it at least works when the site runs. I think I have to disable validation in VS code or something.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to have been able to help :)

Comment: Actually one thing your code returns the object list of the storageItems not the parent selectStorage. so I think I might have to do object assign or something to make it look like "SelectedStorage" changes otherwise none of the react stuff will update.

Comment: Ah cool, as long as the reducer returns an entirely new state object, it doesn't really matter how it gets there.  Good luck!